# sequelize - update row without altering the updated_at field

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am using **sequelize.js** library as ORM in node development. When update a row using **sequelize**, **'updated_at'** field changed to current time-stamp. **I would like to know how can I prevent this ?** Without changing **'updated_at'** field I would like to update other fields using sequlize API, not running raw query.

Answer (score 13):

According to http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update you can use the "silent" option to run an update query but not update the updateAt field.

> options.silent Boolean
>   optional
>   default: false
>   If true, the updatedAt timestamp will not be updated.

```
myModelInstance.update(values, {
    silent: true
})
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer you don't need to change the schema for this solution

Answer (score 0):

In your model definition, you can [turn timestamps off](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#configuration) for specific fields.

> If you want sequelize to handle timestamps, but only want some of them, or want your timestamps to be called something else, you can override each column individually:

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('foo',  { /* bla */ }, {
  // don't forget to enable timestamps!
  timestamps: true,

  // I don't want createdAt
  createdAt: false,

  // I want updatedAt to actually be called updateTimestamp
  updatedAt: 'updateTimestamp'

  // And deletedAt to be called destroyTime (remember to enable paranoid for this to work)
  deletedAt: 'destroyTime',
  paranoid: true
});
```

Otherwise, you can turn timestamps off and handle them manually per-update as you want to.